# Can I create a reusable .xib file that I can actually view in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've looked at all of the questions on StackOverflow that come up related to Swift and Xcode 7, but I can't seem to find a solution that allows me to do both.

I've figured out the `layoutSubviews` allows me to lay out a view and will display it in the storyboard. I also know that `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` will let me load dummy data into the view *specifically* for Interface Builder.

I've also figured out that I can link a class to the File's Owner of a custom .xib file and load it as follows within the class:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: coder)

    contentView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyNib", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! UIView
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
    contentView.frame = self.bounds

    self.addSubview(contentView)
}
```

My problem is that I can't seem to accomplish having *both* of these things work together. I've tried moving the `.loadNibNamed` method and everything into the `layoutSubviews` method, but then the rendering agents don't respond.

Is it possible to achieve both of these means? I'd like to be able to edit the code, view it in the custom .xib, and see it everywhere in the storyboard that I've placed it.